# How to detect cause of Null Pointer Exception on Android Extensions inside fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

In my android application, I am using `Kotlin Android Extensions` for accessing views from XML layout inside fragments and activities. This works well in almost all scenarios but I am constantly getting a null pointer crash report on crashlytics when the app is in use of actual users. I am unable to reproduce this issue or understand the cause of this issue.

The crash is on a fragment that has `Kotlin Android Extensions` usage.

**Below is my code:**

**Kotlin File**

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_documents.*

@Keep
class BottomNavFragment : Fragment() {
    private val activityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel by activityViewModels()
    lateinit var mainActivity: MainActivity

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_documents, container, false)
        mainActivity = activity as MainActivity
        return rootView
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() =
            BottomNavFragment().apply {

            }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        try {
            setUpTabLayout()
            handleViewModelObservers()
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    private fun handleViewModelObservers() {
        activityViewModel.isBackToHomeEnabled.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
            { isHomeEnabled ->
                if (isHomeEnabled!!) {
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(1)?.select()

                }
            })
    }


    private fun setUpTabLayout() {
        try {
            if (mainActivity != null && activityViewModel != null && viewPager != null &&tabLayout!=null) {
                val adapter = FilesViewPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)
                adapter.addFragments()
                viewPager.adapter = adapter
                viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 4
                viewPager.currentItem = 1
                viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
                    override fun onPageScrolled(
                        position: Int,
                        positionOffset: Float,
                        positionOffsetPixels: Int
                    ) {

                    }

                    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                        mainActivity.clearSearch()
                    }

                    override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
                    }

                })
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
                tabLayout.getTabAt(0)?.icon = mainActivity.getDrawable(R.drawable.test1)
                tabLayout.getTabAt(1)?.icon = mainActivity.getDrawable(R.drawable.test2)
                tabLayout.getTabAt(2)?.icon = mainActivity.getDrawable(R.drawable.test3)
                tabLayout.getTabAt(3)?.icon = mainActivity.getDrawable(R.drawable.test3)
                tabLayout.getTabAt(4)?.icon = mainActivity.getDrawable(R.drawable.test5)

                tabLayout.getTabAt(0)?.text = getString(R.string.test1)
                tabLayout.getTabAt(1)?.text = getString(R.string.test2)
                tabLayout.getTabAt(2)?.text = getString(R.string.test3)
                tabLayout.getTabAt(3)?.text = getString(R.string.test4)
                tabLayout.getTabAt(4)?.text = getString(R.string.test5)
            }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
    }


}
```

**XML Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".views.fragments.BottomNavFragment">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />


    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_round_view_white"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/ThemeTextAppearanceTab">

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabLayout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Crash Report**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: viewPager must not be null
       at mypackagename.views.fragments.BottomNavFragment$setUpTabLayout$1.run(BottomNavFragment.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

**What I have learned so far:**

Kotlin Android Extensions actually have `findViewById` , `findViewCache` and `clearFindViewByIdCache` implementation.
And as mentioned in this [article](https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/)

> The problem with fragments is that the view can be recreated but the
> fragment instance will be kept alive. What happens then? This means
> that the views inside the cache would be no longer valid.

So, how I can know that the view is no longer valid? Or, what I can do to prevent this crash?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android extensions plugin is deprecated and the official proposal is to use `ViewBinding` instead which provided compile time access to the views of an xml layout without the need to do `viewFindById` on each view you have.

[This](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) page here will provide you with the steps to set up your code to use view binding, make sure to check the code snippet on a fragment to clear the reference you have on the views